# Chrome Debugger since update 120: Breakpoints not working when using the "debugger" keyword

Tags: google-chrome, debugging

Since the recent Chrome update to version 120, I've encountered a perplexing issue. When using the "debugger" keyword in my code to set a breakpoint, nothing happens. Initially, I suspected an issue on my macOS machine, but after updating Chrome on my PC, the same problem occurred. Has anyone else experienced this issue, or am I alone in this?

I've already submitted a "report," but it seems like throwing a message into the void. If anyone has insights on resolving this issue or has faced a similar situation, I would greatly appreciate any assistance. Thanks in advance!

Comment: And if anyone knows whether this issue is already known and if there's an open ticket somewhere, I would be very grateful if you could leave a link in the comments for me to follow the situation. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I'm not certain if it's specifically build 120; it seems to be that version, but it could be an earlier release. It's a bit confusing, especially considering the mismatch between macOS and Windows. I'll edit the question if necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the Chrome DevTools settings and uncheck this exclusion rule:

[image]

p.s. As noted in the other answer, excluding based on filenames like `/node_modules/` by default tends to disable debugging entirely in lots of contexts.

Comment: It works, thank. Welcome on SO, I've edited your answer to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this, it solved my problem.  I experimented with the custom exclusion rule, the problem is having "/node_modules/" there.  Which is counter intuitive to me.

Comment: Hi Ian, Welcome on SO, I know that you cannot comment on SO since you do not have enough reputation but you should not comment with answer. you should delete this answer